# Как работать с svn через HTTP прокси на Ubuntu?

Tags: http, svn, прокси

При попытке извлечения кода svn выдает следующую ошибку:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://...': Не удалось разрешить имя хоста `...': 
Host not found (http://...)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нужно прописать параметры прокси в настройках svn.

```
sudo nano /etc/subversion/servers
[global]
http-proxy-host = defaultproxy.whatever.com
http-proxy-port = 7000
```